# Why the filtering of smaller dates does not work?

Tags: python, pandas

The example below shows the problem: no filtering for date < date1 ... thanks!

```
df_test = df[1:5]
print(df_test)
date1 = "04-05-1992"
print(df_test.date >= date1)
```

```
    date       open  high   low  close  volume
1  30/04/1992  2.02  2.32  1.95   1.98       0
2  04/05/1992  2.32  2.32  2.02   2.21  115160
3  05/05/1992  2.27  2.43  2.27   2.27       0
4  06/05/1992  2.43  2.54  2.43   2.43       0

1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True

Name: date, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Those dates don't look like they've been parsed as dates. I'd imagine they'd be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: Hi AKX... I have tried to use something like:
pd.to_datetime([parse(df_test.date[i], dayfirst=True) for i in range(len(df_test.date))])  
but I get error... please help to modify date format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates and times are essentially their own component in pandas. See the supporting documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

I cannot see your code, but I'd wager you haven't setup the columns to be recognized as dates and times yet. Try that first. If this does not work, let me know and if possible post more of your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, zerecees. Excellent link, that´s a lot!
I will put the solution below, for interested readers!
df_test = df.date[1:5]
df_test2 = pd.to_datetime(df_test, dayfirst=True)
print(df_test2)
date1 = "1992-05-04"
print(df_test2 >= date1)

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for posting the solution. Have a great day!

Comment: You, too!   See you in other posts (please)...  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to open this new post, for better visualization.  :)

```
df_test = df.date[1:5]
df_test2 = pd.to_datetime(df_test, dayfirst=True)
print(df_test2)
date1 = "1992-05-04"
print(df_test2 >= date1)
```

1   1992-04-30

2   1992-05-04

3   1992-05-05

4   1992-05-06

Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

1    False

2     True

3     True

4     True

Name: date, dtype: bool